# To overcome differences in format of ifconfig Ubuntu16.04 and Ubuntu17.01

Tags: network-interface

Background:

I am checking the list available interfaces on Linux using the ifconfig  command.

However there is a difference in the format of the output of ifconfig in ubuntu 16.04 and ubuntu 17.10.

On checking further , the net-tools  package has been upgraded (from net-tools 1.60 TO net-tools 2.10-alpha)in the ubuntu17.10 and the latest ifconfig outputs the network interface names  with a colon (':').
On older version :

> $ ifconfig --version 
>    net-tools 1.60 ifconfig 1.42 (2001-04-13)
>
> $ ifconfig
>
> enp0s3  Link encap:Ethernet

On the newer version

> $ ifconfig --version net-tools 2.10-alpha
>
> $ifconfig
>
> ens160:  flags=4163  mtu 1500
>
> lo:      flags=73  mtu 65536

This can break some tools which does take into account or expect the extra ':' in the output.

Question:

Is there a way to obtain the list of network interface in a reliable way, such that any change in the format of ifconfig output  does not affect tools using it ? Is there alternative for ifconfig that can be used in consistent manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [net-tools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-tools/) package was [deprecated](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2009/03/msg00780.html) for some time, being replaced by iproute2 (`ip` being the primary tool in that package). Many distributions no longer even ship net-tools as part of their base install.

Development of net-tools has since restarted, but this has resulted in a number of the tools being enhanced in compatibility breaking ways, as you've seen with `ifconfig`. From `NEWS.Debian.gz` on a Debian 9.0 system:

> After 15 years without upstream development, net-tools is being worked on again, fixing many long-standing issues.
>    The bad news is that the output of many commands has changed, and it is sure to break scripts that relied on parsing it.

For that reason it may be an idea to adapt your scripts to use the iproute2 tools. For example, `ip link` should give you similar information to your bare `ifconfig` above. The one downside to this approach is that it breaks compatibility with non-Linux systems, almost all of which use `ifconfig`.

Comment: Thanks iproute2 looks to be supported on most the distributions and embedded distros (via  busybox)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to list all interfaces in Linux from shell is reading `/proc/net/dev`, which have a more stable format than the output of ifconfig(8) from `net-tools`.

For example, to get name of interfaces:

```
whr@debianjessie:~$ sed -r -e 1,2d -e 's/^ +//' -e 's/: .+//' /proc/net/dev
ppp0
lo
eth0
eth1
```